# How to get different objects with Retrofit Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit 1.9.0 in Android Studio to get a response from my REST API.

The method I want to do is GET, on this URL: http://dotfreeride.com/api/rest/adventures.php

I successfully retrieved the response for another API but that had only 1 object, this has 3 big objects.

My IApiMethods interface is like this:

```
@GET("/adventures.php")
JSONObject getAdventures(
      Callback<AdventuresApi> cb
);
```

My AdventuresApi (Model class) is like this:

```
public class AdventuresApi {
    public String adventure_id;
    public String trimaps_context;
    public String name;
    public String video_url;

    public List<ArrayPoi> array_poi;

    public class ArrayPoi {
        String poi_id;
        String name;
        String lat;
        String lng;
        String video_url;
    }
}
```

My Retrofit call in the Activity is like this:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_URL)
            .build();
    IApiMethods methods = restAdapter.create(IApiMethods.class);
    Callback callback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void success(Object o, Response response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e("JSON", "NO DATA!");
        }
    };
    methods.getAdventures(callback);
```

I don't really know how to get the objects, I want to get the name of the object (Example: where trimaps_context is "verb", I need the name "Powder Hound")

For a single object I successfully did it like this in `onResponse(Object o, Response response)`:

```
(ProfileApi) profileData = (ProfileApi) o;
Log.e("JSON", profileData.name + " " + profileData.email);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You are trying to combine both synchronous and asynchronous call. If you want to perform a request asynchronously you have to define it like this:

```
@GET("/adventures.php")
void getAdventures(
        Callback<List<AdventuresApi>> cb
);
```

2) Do not create `RestAdapter` instance everytime you call request. It's really heavyweight operation. Use [singleton pattern](https://gist.github.com/laaptu/feb3cae85f07c0c5fe3e#file-apimanager-java). You can then simply call:

```
ApiManager.getAdapter().getAdventures(...);
```

3) Object mapping is provided by parametrized `Callback` class:

```
ApiManager.getAdapter().getAdventures(
    new Callback<List<AdventuresApi>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<AdventuresApi> adventures, Response response) {
            // here you can access the adventures list
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            // handle error
        }
    });
```